# Node.js: get path from the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a service called "localhost:3000/returnStat" that should take a file path as parameter. For example '/BackupFolder/toto/tata/titi/myfile.txt'.

How can I test this service on my browser?
How can I format this request using Express for instance?

```
exports.returnStat = function(req, res) {

var fs = require('fs');
var neededstats = [];
var p = __dirname + '/' + req.params.filepath;

fs.stat(p, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    neededstats.push(stats.mtime);
    neededstats.push(stats.size);
    res.send(neededstats);
});
};
```

Comment: Yep create a REST call see this article http://erichonorez.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/how-create-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-express/

Comment: and with the browser, just for quick tests

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');
var fs   = require('fs');

var neededstats = [];

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/index.html' || req.url == '/') {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data) {
            res.end(data);
        });
    } else {
        var p = __dirname + '/' + req.params.filepath;
        fs.stat(p, function(err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            neededstats.push(stats.mtime);
            neededstats.push(stats.size);
            res.send(neededstats);
        });
    }
}).listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
console.log('Server running.');
```

I have not tested your code but other things works

**If you want to get the path info from request url**

```
 var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
 console.log(url_parts);
 console.log(url_parts.pathname);
```

1.If you are getting the URL parameters still not able to read the file just correct your file path in my example. If you place index.html in same directory as server code it would work...

2.if you have big folder structure that you want to host using node then I would advise you to use some framework like expressjs

**If you want raw solution to file path**

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start() {
function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

source : http://www.nodebeginner.org/

Comment: My code works, but how can I retrive the file path (req parameter such as '/BackupFolder/toto/tata/titi/myfile.txt')

Comment: Note, `url.parse()` is deprecated in favour of `new URL()`, but the later fails if you pass it `'/'` =/

Answer (score 18):

simply call `req.url`. that should do the work. you'll get something like `/something?bla=foo`

Comment: The path in your example is `/something`.

Comment: use `req.url.match('^[^?]*')[0]` to only show the path

Comment: I feel like there's a builtin that doesn't require messy regex

Comment: There is, it's https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Answer (score 8):

You can use this in `app.js` file .

```
var apiurl = express.Router();
apiurl.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    next();
});
app.use('/', apiurl);
```

Comment: Use `hostname` not host.

Answer (score 7):

A more modern solution that utilises the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) WebAPI:

```js
(req, res) => {
  const { pathname } = new URL(req.url || '', `https://${req.headers.host}`)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
```

or

`req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.originalUrl` // I like this one as it survives from proxy server, getting the original host name

Comment: Use `hostname` not host.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg req.get('hostname') only got return with undefined. using only host is doing fine

Comment: Try `req.hostname` I mean. See docs: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname

Answer (score 3):

Based on @epegzz suggestion for the regex.

```
( url ) => {
  return url.match('^[^?]*')[0].split('/').slice(1)
}
```

returns an array with paths.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this `const { pathname } = req?._parsedUrl || {};` and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Combining solutions above when using express request:

```
let url=url.parse(req.originalUrl);
let page = url.parse(uri).path?url.parse(uri).path.match('^[^?]*')[0].split('/').slice(1)[0] : '';
```

this will handle all cases like

```
localhost/page
localhost:3000/page/
/page?item_id=1
localhost:3000/
localhost/
```

etc. Some examples:

```
> urls
[ 'http://localhost/page',
  'http://localhost:3000/page/',
  'http://localhost/page?item_id=1',
  'http://localhost/',
  'http://localhost:3000/',
  'http://localhost/',
  'http://localhost:3000/page#item_id=2',
  'http://localhost:3000/page?item_id=2#3',
  'http://localhost',
  'http://localhost:3000' ]
> urls.map(uri => url.parse(uri).path?url.parse(uri).path.match('^[^?]*')[0].split('/').slice(1)[0] : '' )
[ 'page', 'page', 'page', '', '', '', 'page', 'page', '', '' ]
```