# Parse special characters in url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have next url:

```
postgres://someuser:pas#%w#@rd-some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

I am parsing it by next way:

```
const url = require('url');
const { hostname: host, port, auth, path } = url.parse(bdUrl);
    
const [user, password] = auth.split(':');
```

It fails with next error:

```
  const [user, password] = auth.split(':');
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
```

If I am removing special symbols (% #) from password, everything works fine.

Comment: `postgres://someuser:pas#%w#@rd-some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432` is not a valid URL - you need to `encodeURIComponent("pas#%w#@rd")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: nope, url is hardcoded and it works perfect without special chars. Also I can extract password separately

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be the # in he password.  If you look at the definition of a url
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL for example)

```
URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
authority = [userinfo@]host[:port]
```

If you look at how the url parser interprets that url

with some code like:

```
const url = require('url');
const parsed = url.parse('postgres://someuser:pas#%w#@rd-some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432');
console.log(parsed);
```

you will get some output like:

```
Url {
  protocol: 'postgres:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'someuser',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'someuser',
  hash: '#%w#@rd-some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432',
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/:pas',
  path: '/:pas',
  href: 'postgres://someuser/:pas#%w#@rd-some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432' }
```

The error you get is because the auth element returns null

if you urlencode the username and password
so the url becomes

```
'postgres://someuser%3Apas%23%25w%23@some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432'
```

you can see the output is correctly parsed

```
Url {
  protocol: 'postgres:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: 'someuser:pas#%w#',
  host: 'some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432',
  port: '5432',
  hostname: 'some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: null,
  path: null,
  href: 'postgres://someuser:pas%23%25w%23@some-db.cgosdsd8op.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432' }
```

Comment: But I have whole url on input, I can't encode username and password before

Comment: you may be able to extract the username and pasword using a regex for example `url.match(/\/\/([^@]+)@/)`

Comment: also this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145778/how-to-fetch-username-and-password-from-url-using-basic-authentication-in-node-j