# how to redirect to another page from a node.js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have been struggling for the pas few days i want to redirect to another page from my node.js server.
first by website is redirecting me to my server to do a task but when that task is done i want the server to redirect me back to my website.
here is the node js server code.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongourl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    var urlQuery = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    removeItem(urlQuery.itemToRemove);
    addItem(urlQuery.itemToAdd);
    **// i have been trying to redirect to my html site **
    **// i have got a error saying TypeError: res.redirect is not a function**
    res.redirect('index.html');
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);



function removeItem(remove) {
    if (remove !== undefined) {
        MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("mydb");
            var myquery = {
                itemName: remove
            };
            dbo.collection("shoppingCart").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("deleted:" + myquery);
                db.close();
            });
        });
    }
}

function addItem(create) {
    if (create !== undefined) {
        MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("mydb");
            var myobj = {
                itemName: create
            };
            dbo.collection("shoppingCart").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("document inserted:" + myobj);
                db.close();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error when redirecting? or what is issue that you're facing?

Comment: TypeError: res.redirect is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because response.redirect() is an express function and your app is based purely on nodejs http library.

You can accomplish what you have mentioned this way:

```
res.writeHead(301,{Location: 'your-location'});
res.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the server properly. Try to keep your code clean,Write separate API for serving index.html, not inside creating the server.

Comment: my index.html is in another page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931452/node-js-get-path-from-the-request

Comment: Please go through Express framework which makes your task easier. You can also install express-generator package which provided you basic folder structure.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator. Use this package.

Comment: yep i am using express now it is go good I get what you mean

Comment: can you upvote my answer if its helpful. Thank you

Comment: srry i dont got enough reputation :(

Comment: its been 2 years ty for this advice

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: res.redirect is not a function

This is because `res.redirect` is an express function and you're using plain `http` node server.

You can consider using `express` for handling redirects for you.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongourl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

// express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

// for templating
// create `views/` folder
// and place `index.pug` and `redirected-page.pug`
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
  res.render('redirected-page');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var urlQuery = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  Promise.all([
    removeItem(urlQuery.itemToRemove),
    addItem(urlQuery.itemToAdd),
  ]).then(() => {
    res.redirect('redirect');
  });
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

function removeItem(remove) {
  if (remove !== undefined) {
    MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db('mydb');
      var myquery = {
        itemName: remove,
      };
      dbo.collection('shoppingCart').deleteOne(myquery, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('deleted:' + myquery);
        db.close();
      });
    });
  }
}

function addItem(create) {
  if (create !== undefined) {
    MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db('mydb');
      var myobj = {
        itemName: create,
      };
      dbo.collection('shoppingCart').insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('document inserted:' + myobj);
        db.close();
      });
    });
  }
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running at ${port}!`));
```