# Get all the url params in Node js @ httpGet in array

Tags: node.js, http-get, query-string

I am a beginner in node js. I am trying to do a `@httpGet` request. My base url is `localhost:3000`. If I define the get like

```
@httpGet('/:path')
```

and give the url like

```
localhost:3000/index.html
```

Then I am getting the `index.html` as the path v alue.

But if I pass multiple values like

```
localhost:3000/assets/js/app.js
```

I would like the `path` to return the value `assets/js/app.js`.

But it is not happening. Is there any way to get this value as a string? Or return all these value as an array?

Please help.

Comment: Where is `@httpGet` come from?

Comment: @hoangdv, `@httpGet` is from my typescript controller file.

Comment: What is your framework or library?

Comment: @hoangdv, I am using this in `Node JS`. So in the `Node js` I am trying a get call.

Comment: If you are using expressjs, let's try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525928/how-to-get-request-path-with-express-req-object

Comment: if it is native `http` module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931452/node-js-get-path-from-the-request

Comment: @hoangdv, Thanks you for the hints. Let me try this.